# Can't insert into newly created mongolab db

Tags: java, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I'm having problems inserting documents into a mongoLab instance.

I'm connecting to the instance using this command :

```java
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(uri));
```

with `uri` that look like this :

```
mongodb://heroku_app1234:random_password@ds029017.mongolab.com:29017/heroku_app1234
```

the user `heroku_app1234` has the status `readOnly` to `false`

and inserting my document like this :

```java
Jongo jongo = new Jongo(client.getDB("myDb"));
MongoCollection collection = jongo.getCollection("myCollection");
collection.save(someBean);
client.close();
```

and the server crash with this exception :

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "ds029017.mongolab.com:29017" , "err" : "not authorized for insert on myDb.myCollection" , "code" : 16544 , "n" : 0 , "lastOp" : { "$ts" : 0 , "$inc" : 0} , "connectionId" : 21382 , "ok" : 1.0}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're connecting and authenticating to one database (heroku_app1234) but then switching to another (myDB). You're getting the error `not authorized for insert on myDb.myCollection` as a result.

When you grab the database to pass into the `Jongo()` constructor you should be sure to grab the same one as used in the URI. It looks like you're using Java. If so, this tweak to your code may work for you:

```
MongoClientUri uri = new MongoClientUri("mongodb://heroku_app1234:random_password@ds029017.mongolab.com:29017/heroku_app1234");
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
Jongo jongo = new Jongo(client.getDB(uri.getDatabase()));
MongoCollection collection = jongo.getCollection("myCollection");
collection.save(someBean);
client.close();
```

We have some basic connection examples in our [Language Center](http://docs.mongolab.com/languages/), including one for [Java](https://github.com/mongolab/mongodb-driver-examples/blob/master/java/JavaSimpleExample.java) that you can feel free to pull from.

```
// Standard URI format: mongodb://[dbuser:dbpassword@]host:port/dbname
MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db"); 
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
DB db = client.getDB(uri.getDatabase());
```